# is there simpliest way to "shortcut" SQL Query? SELECT * FROM table WHERE ... OR COLUMN1 LIKE ''%tshirt%" OR COLUMN2 LIKE '%tshirt%' OR

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, search

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE status = 'Finished' 
     AND aukcja LIKE '%tshirt%' OR name LIKE '%tshirt%' OR comment LIKE '%tshirt%'
```

table has several columns and i'd like search "tshirt" in every column
[image: search]

what should the query look like? Should I refer to every column in the table or is there some magic key word maybe?
something like:

```
select * from table where status = 'finished' AND COLUMN INCLUDE '%tshirt%'
```

IMO listing several column names is pointless in this case

which query will be more efficient with huge databases? select * from table WHERE statement SORT BY ... or select 5 COLUMNS from table WHERE statement SORT BY ...

in the second case, half of the table is supposed to be returned, but the data will have to be sorted anyway and I wonder how database engines work
is it better for them to operate on the entire table and separate the user's query, or maybe they will process this data faster when the search engine is programmed so that it does not search for strings in the date/time/etc columns - don't search %tshirt% in column date_finished and date_of_order and id

many auction sites have filtering, but by default they are all turned off and we get results that fit the category. later, the accuracy algorithms work, but if we choose filters, there are fewer results, so is it a more demanding operation for the engine than returning answers without filters selected?

Comment: Your query is wrong, you should use ( like `status = 'Finished' AND (aukcja LIKE '%tshirt%' OR name LIKE '%tshirt%' OR comment LIKE '%tshirt%')`

Comment: In addition `and concat(aukcja, name, comment) like '%tshirt%'`

Comment: I suggest creating a [fulltext index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/fulltext-search.html), and using `match(aukcja, name, comment) against ('tshirt' in boolean mode)`.